# Create java entities for join table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a four-level hierarchy of java entities. Each level consists of an id and a list of entries of the next level.

E.g. (simplified to make the structure clear)

```
public class Top {
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   List<Upper> uppers;
}

public class Upper {
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   Top parent;

   @OneToMany
   List<Lower> lowers;
}

public class Lower {
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   Upper parent;

   @OneToMany
   List<Bottom> bottoms;
}

public class Bottom {
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   Lower parent;
}
```

All data is stored in a single table/view with complete sets of top_id, upper_id, lower_id, bottom_id. So an entry's PK is the complete set of all four ids.

So rows would look like

```
top_id, upper_id, lower_id, bottom_id
1,      2,        3,        4
1,      5,        6,        7
8,      9,        10,       11
...
```

I tried to uses `@Embedded` or `@EmbeddedId`, had a look into `@MapsId` and some other annotations listed here: https://dzone.com/articles/all-jpa-annotations-mapping-annotations
Most of the time I fail at the point where I need to specify the Id (composite or not) of `Top`.
I am out of ideas on how to solve the problem. After all, I do not really need this model. I would be happy with a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>>`. However, I need to get this data without postprocessing in my spring boot application.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Even I think the table is not well designed. What's the primary key of this table?

Comment: Thank you for having a look into the issue. It's just a customer's "this is what you get, work with it" table. The PK is a composite of all four entries.
If I would have the entities that are linked in the table I could just use it as a join table, but all I have is this id-table.